# How do you stop an input/output table from loading and return to the process flow in SAS EG?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

SAS can take a very long time to load an output table after you click on it from the process flow, is there a way to cancel it? I've wasted hours waiting for tables to load, I am hoping there is a way to exit the "Input Data" or "Output Data" tabs and return to the process flow window.

Comment: What version of EG are you running; and are you connected to a server or a local SAS installation?

Comment: @Joe I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide 7.1 64-bit on a remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to directly stop the table from loading; in my brief tests, `ctrl+break` and `esc` don't stop it, which are the usual possibilities, and both do work in some places in EG.  I will say that this is somewhat of a weakness in EG in general; it's not perfect at handling things in the background and allowing you to interrupt, though it's improved greatly over the years.

What you can do to avoid this being a problem, at least possibly, is to go to the Tools->Options->Data->Performance option screen, and limit the `Maximum dimensions to display in the data grid` value to something well under the default 1,000,000.  Change it to 50,000 or something else that is a reasonable compromise between your needs and how long it takes to connect to datasets.

Alternately, you can prevent datasets from appearing on the process flow by altering the option in Tools->Options->Results->Results General `Maximum number of output data sets to add to the project` to zero.  That doesn't prevent you from browsing datasets; you would just have to do it through the Servers tab on the lower left (in the default setup).

Comment: All the above said, it's also a good idea to hop over to communities.sas.com and see if anyone there has a suggestion; there is a much larger EG user community there, plus some of the developers post (and the lead of SAS Communities, Chris Hemedinger, used to be an EG developer).

Comment: I asked the question on [communities.sas.com](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/How-do-you-stop-an-input-output-table-from-loading-and-return-to/m-p/250990#M17732) as well, the responses there confirm what you said about there not being a kill switch. Seems like the best course of action is to change the performance settings and results settings like you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong then you would **"NOT"** want the Input and Output datasets to open when the process is run. Then **uncheck** the highlighted options in SAS EG, Goto **Tools--> Options --> Results --> Results General** and uncheck the options shown in image below.  [image]

Comment: This doesn't directly relate - OP mentions specifically opening from the PF - but it's good advice nonetheless in this kind of situation.